# Call periodically function with Dojo

Tags: dojo

I need to update data on my site every 1000ms. How to call function periodically with Dojo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval).

The function takes a function and a number as parameters. The function is called every *n* milliseconds where *n* is the second parameter.

For example:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    alert('called every 2000 milliseconds');
}, 2000);
```

To stop the interval you will have to call [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.clearInterval)

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

Or if you just want to run something after *n* milliseconds make a call to [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert('also called after 2000 milliseconds BUT, just once');
}, 2000);
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Updated the link.